# Artifactory remote repos and Terracota

Tags: artifactory

I want to setup my maven settings.xml file to download all the external dependencies from Artifactory cache instead of download them directly from any of the public repositories like repo1, repo2 or Jboss. I followed the instructions at http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution at but I'm stuck with an error with the terracota library, the error is:

```
    Could not find artifact net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-terracotta:jar:2.5.0 in remote-repos
```

I tried adding terracota repository at the remote repositories section but this didn't worked either.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of possibilities:

1. Your remote-repos cache isn't configured to point to the remote repository that contains the Terracotta files
2. Your build isn't using the correct organization or module name when resolving the dependency on Terracotta.

Could you add some info to your question detailing where exactly you are seeing the error message, and whether you can browse to ehcache-terracotta version 2.5.0 in Artifactory ?

Comment: I see the error executing a maven clean install command. I browse the ehcache-terracota 2.5.0 in the artifactory repository and it was not there. Here is the only ehcache jar I'm including in the pom file:
        <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>`code`

Comment: Here is a screenshot of how I'm adding terracota repo in aretifactory http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/capturehhy.jpg/

Answer (score 1):

Please add the terracotta repository to your artifactory

This is the URL= http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases
Don't worry if the test of the repo doesn't work...

The last step is to go to Edit Virtual Repository and add the new terracotta repo to the virtual repository called "Remote Repo".